# Chinese songs don't show up in Apollo library

Tags: cyanogenmod, music

I have some Chinese songs on my LG Optimus G, which I copied to my music folder along with the rest of the songs. All songs show up in Apollo (Cyanogenmod's standard player), but not the Chinese ones.

I have tried changing the filenames to western alphabet. I have put them in a folder with a name in western alphabet. I have refreshed the media library. I have rebooted. I have deleted the data from Apollo. Yet to no avail. The only thing I've not changed is the MP3 Tag which contains Chinese characters, but that really shouldn't be a problem. I can open each individual song with Apollo from within a file manager, and they play and their MP3 Tag information shows.

The songs played perfectly before I made the move to Cyanogenmod.

How can I make them show up in the library?

Comment: Not sure whether it solves the issue, but you could delete cache/data from the media library ("Media Storage" -- the provider used by the Media Scanner, where all collected information is stored) as well. That would force the Media Scanner to refresh the entire library.

Answer (score 0):

I am using CM10.1 with my S2. I have Chinese songs (with Chinese text), and can play them on Apollo.

Your player probably can't see the files. Try to re-scan them using the [Rescan SD Card](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uberullu.rescansd) app.